# the alternative to tf.image.decode_image?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I find that the runtime of `tf.image.decode_image` is very long under the version of tensorflow 1.14. but it is ok under the version of 2.0

```
import os
def create_dataset(csv_filename):
    # Do things here, return the dataset
    # return dataset
    csvdataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(csv_filename,[tf.string, tf.string])
    list_raw = []
    list_reg = []
    for element in csvdataset:
        raw_element = tf.io.decode_image(tf.io.read_file(root_dir+tf.strings.substr(element[0], 2, tf.size(element[0])-2)), dtype=tf.dtypes.uint16)       
       # seg_element = tf.image.decode_image(tf.io.read_file(root_dir+tf.strings.substr(element[1], 2, tf.size(element[0])-2)), dtype=tf.dtypes.uint8)
       # list_raw.append(raw_element)
       # list_reg.append(seg_element)
    #dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list_raw, list_reg))
    #return dataset
```